# Consolidate irregular date values in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with a column of string values that I want to convert to date format.  In R I usually break this down to a series of steps substituting the `??:??` with `12:00`, stripping the time, appending it to the end and converting with a POSIX function.

I am trying to replicate that in Python in a more *pythonic* manner.

Here is an exceprt from my `DataFrame` (150,000 rows) as `Series`

```
index  date
0    21/08/2001 10:20
1     19/09/2005 9:50
2     ??:?? 04-Jun-01
3    16/08/2004 7:15 
4     ??:?? 04-Jan-01 
5     23/01/2001 9:25 
6    24/01/2001 11:16 
7     ??:?? 05-Feb-01 
8     24/01/2001 8:30 
9    24/01/2001 15:15
```

Here is what I have tried (I have called the excerpt `tmp`.):

I thought I could use list comprehensions and a regular expression replacement as follow:

`[re.sub('\\?\\?:\\?\\?', '12:00', tmp) for i in tmp[i]]`

What I would like to do is get the replacement of `??:??` with `12:00` and then generalise it so I can use it with `tmp.apply`.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Series.str.replace()`:

```
date = """21/08/2001 10:20
19/09/2005 9:50
??:?? 04-Jun-01
16/08/2004 7:15 
??:?? 04-Jan-01 
23/01/2001 9:25 
24/01/2001 11:16 
??:?? 05-Feb-01 
24/01/2001 8:30 
24/01/2001 15:15""".split("\n")

s = pd.Series(date)
s.str.replace("\?\?:\?\?", "12:00")
```

Comment: Ouch! This is awesome. I am definitely using more Python and less R.